# PHP Regex match if last three characters contain two letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Basically I have this but its either or:

```
[en].{0,2}$
```

What I want to do is detect 'en' and not 'e' or 'n'. Just 'en' in that order but in the last three characters.

So it should match

```
attend
```

but not:

```
attained
```

So it must detect if the last three characters contain 'en' in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just 'en' in that order but in the last three characters.

That means you need to match `en` that is either at the end of the string or `en` that has any single char after it at the end of the string.

You may use

```
en.?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aBcz7l/2)

**Details**

- `en` - `en` substring
- `.?`  - any optional char
- `$` - end of string.

If you may have line breaks in the input, use `s` modifier: `/en.?$/s`.

Comment: That's great, it works perfectly. Yes so basically it contains 'en' within the last three characters.

Answer (score 1):

If `bean` is also acceptable use this regex:

```
/e.?n$|en.?$/g
```

[**`[Regex Demo]`**](https://regex101.com/r/ARa1tG/6)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the regex

```
^.*(?=.*en.*).{3}$
```

see the [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yheWa1/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last three characters starts with en, You can use this regex

```
en.$
```

---

If you want the last three characters ends with en, You can use this regex

```
.en$
```

---

If both cases are acceptable, You can use this regex

```
(.en|en.)$
```